# Autocorrect misspelled word to first suggestion in Google Documents

Tags: google-docs, spell-check

In Google Documents, how can I have misspelled words auto-corrected to the first suggestion?

For instance let's suppose the user writes `helo world` in Google Documents. Then without any action from user, it should automatically change to `hello world`.

I am hoping for solutions using scripts or add-ons.

Comment: maybe there are other products rather than google doc than has this functionality ?

Answer (score 4):

In the menu, `Tools > Preferences` you have `Automatic substitution` (make sure it's checked). There you can enter words you want to have automatically changed.

This would mainly be used for common misspellings, as it requires you to enter all the corrections yourself. I don't think there's a auto-correct function as on your phone, which automatically chooses the spelling it believes is correct.

If you misspell a word, you can right-click it and choose "Always correct to [correction]", helps speeding up the process somewhat.

As of now it does not seem to work with multiple words, so adding "helo world" doesn't work. It will only recognize single words. So changing "helo" to "hello" will work.

Note that it's case insensitive. The replacement will have the same case as the original word ("Helo" > "Hello", "HELO" > "HELLO", etc)

You can read more at the [support article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/57859?hl=en). There you can read about "Spelling suggestions" and "Autocorrection" as different things (you'd want the combination).

Comment: The question was about to autocorrect to first google suggestion however, your answer is partially fine as it gives me an idea to import dictionary. As you said, maybe an approach is to Always correct to [correction] until you end up with a fine dictionary !

Comment: Yeah, I believe that's the closest to it you can come right now.

Comment: Could be nice if there is a solution using scripts/ add-ons

Comment: I did a quick search for add-ons before answering and didn't find anything. I believe scripting would take quite some time. Their [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/) doesn't mention autocorrect or suggestions, so I believe you'd have to script the entire thing by yourself.